# Multi-Option type in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I archive a kind of Option type which either returns something of type T or of type Error?

I am doing some web requests and the responses are either "ok" and contain the object or the call returns an error, in which case I want to provide an Error object with the reason of error.

So something like:

```
def myRequest() : Result[MyObject] {
  if (thereWasAnError) Error(reason) else MyObject 
}
```

Comment: By the way, this kind of thing is better handled by Scalaz `Validation`.

Comment: Can you provide a link with an example? What is the advantage? It would be an additional dependency...

Comment: Look it up -- both on Stack Overflow and outside it. It's difficult to explain the advantages, beyond it just being a better abstraction than `Either`. For that matter, Lift also has an alternative -- `Box` -- also a result of `Either` inadequacies.

Comment: Daniel is right, Validation is definitely better. The simple reason being that Validation is right biased and that you can more easily accumulate errors on the left by having a SemiGroup (reducer function basically) for the left/error type. See the following for an excellent intro: https://github.com/mpilquist/scalaz-talk

Comment: Thanks :) I am writing a scala library with that particular problem. I first decided that Exceptions are no choice, as an `Error` from the web service is a result which can happen. Exceptions are not checked. If you would be using a library for a web service, you would prefer Validation, although there is only one type of Error, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## `scala.Either`

[`Either`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) type should be exactly what you want:

```
def myRequest() : Either[String, MyObject] = 
    if (thereWasAnError) 
        Left("Some error message") 
    else 
        Right(new MyObject)
```

`Either` is similar to `Option` but can hold one out of two possible values: *left* or *right*. By convention *right* is OK while *left* is an error.

You can now do some fancy pattern matching:

```
myRequest() match {
    case Right(myObject) =>
        //...
    case Left(errorMsg) =>
        //...
}
```

## `scala.Option.toRight()`

Similarily you can use `Option` and translate it to `Either`. Since typically `*right* values is used for success and left for failure, I suggest using`toRight()`rather than`toLeft()`:

```
def myRequest() : Option[MyObject] =
    if (thereWasAnError)
        None
    else
        Some(new MyObject)

val result: Either[String, MyObject] = myRequest() toRight "Some error message"
```

However returning `Either` directly as a result of `myRequest()` seems more straightforward in this simple example.

Comment: Which is the better way? Either or case classes, like aioobe suggests? I guess in both cases I have to unwrap the object in the "OK" case to get the MyObject result?

Comment: @user3001: `Either` was specifically designed for cases like yours (two types of results, where one is considered an error or failure object). case classes as *aioobe* suggested are much more powerful as you can have more than two options (unlikely in your situation). Also `Either` is built-in. Both solutions can use pattern matching to extract values easily (see my second code snippet and [`Either` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Either.html)).

Comment: I discovered that the Option type has the mehtods {{toLeft}} and {{toRight}} which are really useful. Is there any community standard which of the two arguments should be the Error object?

Comment: What I did was to use toRight to have a shorthand function: `def result[T]( xmlConverter :(NodeSeq) => T) : Either[T, Error] =  error.toRight(xmlConverter(xml)) ` So if there was an error, return an Error object, else create a resulting object from the xml